# How to access OneNote notebooks from anywhere?

Tags: microsoft-onenote-2010

How can I access my MS OneNote notebooks from my laptop, and from my PC in the University securely? (I mean I don't want my files to be published online and shared by other people)

Comment: OneNote integrates with Microsofts SkyDrive which is by default private. Have you already considered using SkyDrive? (If yes, you should include your cons about SkyDrive in your question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use Skydrive.

Share the notebook on Skydrive and access it by logging onto Live.com.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chris_pratley/archive/2006/06/08/syncing-onenote-2007-notes-across-your-many-pcs.aspx

Comment: Will this be safe? meaning will other people can see at my papers?

Comment: You don't have to share the Notebook to actually use it on Live.com.